# How to write a Makefile rule to remove files (clean) only if the files are present?

Tags: makefile

It looks to me like Makefile rules can be roughly classified into "positive" and "negative" ones: "positive" rules create missing or update outdated files, while "negative" ones remove files.

Writing prerequisites for "positive" rules is quite easy: if the target and the prerequisite are file names, `make` by default runs the recipe if the target is missing or outdated (a missing file in this context may be viewed as an infinitely old file).

However, consider a "negative" rule, for example for target `clean`.  A usual way to write it seems to be something like this:

```
clean:
    rm -f *.log *.synctex.gz *.aux *.out *.toc
```

This is clearly not the best way to do:

1. `rm` is executed even when there is nothing to do,
2. its error messages and exit status need to be suppressed with `-f` flag, which has other (possibly undesirable) effects, and
3. the fact that there were nothing to do for target `clean` is not reported to the user, unlike what is normal for "positive" targets.

My question is: how to write a Makefile rule that shall be processed by `make` only if certain files are present?  (Like what would be useful for `make clean`.)

Comment: So your question is not simply about suppressing the error messages with a `-` prefix? i.e. `-rm *.log *.synctex.gz *.aux *.out *.toc`

Comment: Yes, i believe there must be a way to write a rule so that *no errors be committed*, not simply *not reported*. I would also appreciate a polite notification from `make` that there were nothing to remove (and nothing has been removed).

Answer (score 7):

> how to write a Makefile rule that shall be processed by make only if certain files are present? (Like what would be useful for make clean.)

You can do it like so:

```
filenames := a b c

files := $(strip $(foreach f,$(filenames),$(wildcard $(f))))

all: $(filenames)

$(filenames):
    touch $@

clean:
ifneq ($(files),)
    rm -f $(files)
endif
```

Example session:

```
$ make
touch a
touch b
touch c
$ make clean
rm -f a b c
$ make clean
make: Nothing to be done for 'clean'.
```

Useful perhaps for some purposes, but it strikes me as a strained refinement for `make clean`.

Comment: Thanks for a solution.  Here is another analogous use case i've thought of, besides plain `make clean`.  I might want to remove some intermediate auxiliary files under the condition that the targets they are used to build are already built and are newer than these files.

Comment: The GNU make special target [`.INTERMEDIATE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) will auto-delete whatever you consider to be intermediate files when `make` is done.

Comment: But i do not want them to be removed automatically, they can be used for rebuilding.

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily remedied:

```
clean:
    for file in *.log *.synctex.gz *.aux *.out *.toc; do \
        if [ -e "$file" ]; then \
            rm "$$file" || exit 1; \
        else \
            printf 'No such file: %s\n' "$file" \
        fi \
    done
```

The `if` statement is necessary unless your shell supports and has enabled [`nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob) or something similar.

If your `printf` supports `%q` you should use that instead of `%s` to avoid possible corruptions of your terminal when printing weird filenames.

Answer (score -1):

A meta-answer is: are you sure you want to do this?

The other answers suggest to me that the cure is worse than the disease, since one involves an extension to POSIX make (`ifneq`), and the other uses a compound command which spreads over seven lines.  Both of these are sometimes necessary expedients – I'm not criticising either answer – but both are things I avoid in a Makefile if I can.  If I found myself wanting to do this in a `clean` rule, perhaps for the reason you mention in your comment to @MikeKinghans' answer, I'd try quite hard to change the rest of the Makefile to avoid needing this.

Reflecting on your three original points in turn:

1. *rm is executed even when there is nothing to do*: so what? The alternatives still need to, for example, expand the `*.log *.synctex.gz ...` so there's only miniscule efficiency gain to avoiding the `rm`.  `Make` is a high-level tool which generally does not concern itself with efficiency.
2. *its error messages and exit status need to be suppressed with -f flag*: the `-f` flag doesn't generally suppress errors and the exit status, it merely indicates to `rm` that a non-existing or non-permissioned file is not to be regarded as an error.
3. *the fact that there were nothing to do for target clean is not reported to the user*: should the user really care?

The last point is the most interesting.  People asking about `make`, on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, sometimes make things hard for themselves by trying to use it as a procedural language – `make` is not Python, or Fortran.  Instead, it's a *goal programming language* (if we want to get fancy about it): you write snippets of rules to achieve sub-goals, so that the user (you, later) doesn't have to care about the details or the directory's current state, but can simply indicate a goal, and the program does whatever's necessary to get there.  So whether there's is or isn't anything to do, the user ‘shouldn't’ care.

---

I think the short version of this answer is: it's idiomatic to keep `make` rules as simple (and thus as readable and robust) as possible, even at the expense of a little crudity or repetition.

Comment: I think, what i get from your answer is that `make` is unable to do what i want.  I believe this is a bit of a flaw in the design of `make`. As `make` can apply rules when some files are missing, it could as well be made to apply rules when some files are present.  This would not make rules more complex.  I will also comment on the 3 points.

Comment: 1. This is not so much about efficiency, but about correct design.  Would you be equally ready in an ordinary Makefile rule to skip the prerequisites and instead to run the compiler every time but pass some flags which would make it to recompile the file only if it is newer than the output file?

Comment: 2. According to `man rm`, "-f          Attempt to remove the files without prompting for confirmation, regardless of the file's permissions." I might not want to disable confirmation requests or stop verifying the permissions.

Comment: 3. Then why to report that "Nothing to be done" for ordinary targets? Should the user really care?  As to `clean`, i can imagine that in some situations i might appreciate a reminder that i had not created anything since the last `make clean`.

Comment: There's no right or wrong answer here, and I've certainly written some pretty funky Makefile rules in my time. All I was aiming to suggest is that there is an element of style/idiom here. And like email, the death of `make` has been imagined many times in the last couple of decades, but...

Comment: clean target is not a problem, but there are some cases when you want some target: file1 file2 ~file3 which will call ~file3 to be sure that file3 will be removed before target rule body will be run. For example, I want to be sure that all commercial parts of software will be removed before building opensource installation package.

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov I'm not sure I completely follow the scenario, but it sounds like a situation where I'd step back and ask ‘what goal am I really aiming for here?’ (and go for a walk). Perhaps try a 'clean-commercial' real or dummy target? All I'm really saying, I suppose, is that being too clever in Make dependencies, or using too many GNU extensions, is for me a Make ‘code smell’.